# react-intl display currency symbol only

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

Working with react-intl and was looking to display a currency symbol only, after some text like USD$.

From what I have read so far in the documentation guessing FormattedNumber requires a default value.

Just wondering is it possible to display a currency symbol without a number value? such as $ (currently it returns NaN, due to missing number value)

Wondering has anyone run into this kind of issue previously?

Guessing there must be a simple solution.

In the meantime will keep looking for alternative solutions.

Any thought greatly appreciated.

Comment: Specify default value. Do this `FormattedNumber(your_value || 0)`

Comment: @jank thanks for the reply. Not too sure I understand your example fully.
formattedNumber expects a number otherwise it will return NaN.
The only default value it will recognise is a number I'm thinking?
Was wondering if anyone had encountered an alternative way of displaying a currency symbol only (no number value) using react-intl.
like "sometext$" or "USD$"?
Guessing I could just make a simple helper to get around this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since react-intl uses `Intl.NumberFormat` under the hood, you might be able to use [`formatToParts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/formatToParts) to extract just the currency symbol, for example

```js
const symbol = Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currencyDisplay: 'narrowSymbol',
    currency: 'USD'
  })
  .formatToParts(0)
  .filter(part => part.type === 'currency')
  .map(part => part.value)
  .join('')

console.log(symbol)
```

Although, depending on the required [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/formatToParts#browser_compatibility), it might require a polyfill.